# Multiple domains for a single locale

Tags: localization, config

Hi I'm creating a site that will be used in 4 locales which each have their own domain.

- Australia: project.com.au
- New Zealand: project.co.nz
- South Africa: project.co.za
- USA: project.co

In short, from a content management perspective I only want two locales. English AU and English USA. However, I need the content on the au locale to be accessible from the au,nz,za domains.

Is it possible to have an array of URL for one locale config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Multi-Environment](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) configuration to set the [siteUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/site-url) for your two locales, `en_au` and `en_us`, independently for each domain like so:

```
'project.com.au' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_au' => 'http://project.com.au/',
        'en_us' => 'http://project.co/',
    ),
),

'project.co.nz' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_au' => 'http://project.co.nz/',
        'en_us' => 'http://project.co/',
    ),
),

'project.co.za' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_au' => 'http://project.co.za/',
        'en_us' => 'http://project.co/',
    ),
),

'project.co' => array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_au' => 'http://project.com.au/',
        'en_us' => 'http://project.co/',
    ),
),
```

You can also set additional environment / domain specific variables in the config file. You could set the currency or the timezone for each domain:

```
'project.com.au' => array(
    'currency' => 'AUD',
    'timeZone' => 'UTC+10',
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_au' => 'http://project.com.au/',
        'en_us' => 'http://project.co/',
    ),
),
```

This is how you [access such a variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.config) in your templates:

```
{{ craft.config.currency }}
```